# Google Speech to Text - Can't write output to text file

Tags: python, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am attempting to write to a text file. It just seems to fail every time. I can write .write("test") but writing the google transcription output to file seems to fail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

````
import speech_recognition as sr

from os import path

from pprint import pprint

audio_file = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "RobertP.wav")

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

try:
    txt = r.recognize_google(audio, show_all=True)
    pprint (txt)

except:
    print("Didn't work.")

try:
    f = open("tester.txt", "w+")
    f.write(txt)
    f.close()
except:
    print("Couldn't write to file")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Looks like txt is not a string. You can try to convert it to a string with str(txt).

btw:
It's better to remove the try/except for testing reasons to get the error. After the program works you can add it again,.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Where would I add str(txt)? 

I have currently added it after the txt = r.... line

Comment: I get this error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/george/PycharmProjects/SpeechRecog/venv/filerecognition.py", line 21, in <module>
    f.write(txt)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict

```

Comment: str(txt) Returns a string. If you just write str(txt) Nothing will happen. You can do somethink like txt_string = str(txt) or f.write(str(txt))

Comment: That error mens, that you have a dict and not a string. Please post the Output of print(txt).

Comment: That's it! The later of your suggestions worked perfectly (I assume the former would too)

Thanks a lot for your help.